# Android how to trace and clear certain backstack

Tags: android, android-intent, back-stack

My Activity backstack structure looks like this:

> A(Landing page) -> B(List screen) -> C(Details screen)
>   |----> D(Post
>   item screen) -> E(Post result screen)

Both B & D are direct child of A.

I wanted to provide a way for user to view the detail(C) from the result screen(E). While they go away, I wanted to remove D & E so that they can't go back when pressing back. Once jumped when user press back from C then they should go back to A instead.

**EDIT:** However, user can press back on E screen to go back and make change in D screen to fix whatever mistake they made so I kinda have to keep D in backstack as well.

**What is the best way of doing this? Should I prevent D&E from ever going into backstack and handle my own navigation? Is there a way to clear D & E specifically and keep everything else? Or is there a better way to do this?**

I considered using `Clear Top` flag but if user never visits C before Clear top wouldn't work as you can't go back to A afterward.

Answer (score 0):

I use [Activity.finish()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#finish%28%29) to hide a Activity from the backstack.

As an example:

The user sees activity B and starts activity C. After stating of C call finish to hide B from the backstack:

```
  startActivity(<Activity-C intent>);
  finish();
```

Comment: I should have mentioned that E screen also display error message and users are allowed to navigate from E to D via Back press as well. My bad.